# ganglia graphs like munin for cpu, etc?

Tags: munin, ganglia, graph, gmetad, gmond

I'm coming from munin and a CPU graph contains data for system, user, nice, etc ALL on one graph. I just installed ganglia and setup the basic monitoring. It appears that each type of cpu data is a separate graph! WTF is this and can I change the defaults to combine these into a single per host?

That is my question, how do I combine cpu data into a single graph. Also, can I change the layout to something closer to munin's day-week side-by-side layout?

I'm trying to be impartial and give ganglia a chance. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ganglia is designed for monitoring clusters of many, many machines.  It's rather over specified for only a few servers that aren't clustered.  I don't know if you can change the default graphs, but you may be better off sticking with a solution designed for regular servers rather than tailored to high performance clusters.

However, if you want to customise Ganglia's graphs, I think you'll need 3.1 and the following web page,

http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/ganglia/wiki/Custom_graphs

From that page,

> New in the 3.1.x branch of Ganglia is an improved ability for users to
>   create their own custom graphs, similar to the existing load, CPU,
>   memory, network and packet reports. In the 3.0.x branch, all graphs
>   were contained in a monolithic graph.php file, which made adding
>   additional features somewhat difficult. Going forward, all graphs are
>   generated separately, with one PHP file per graph type; including the
>   basic metric graphs.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the summary graphs on the right side:

[image]